GSAP The next element after the element with "pinspacing:false" is loaded too quickly
I added "pinSpacing:false" to "#three". Because I wanted to create an effect where "#four" naturally overlaps and rises when "#three" ends. However, when I added "pinSpacing:false" to "#three", "#four" show before "#three" even ended.
I tried various methods such as changing the start and end points, but I couldn't solve it.
Here is my codepen.
https://codepen.io/SooPK/pen/jOgyNRP
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrap">
  <!--container-->
  <div class="container">
    <section id="one">
      <div class="bg"></div>
    </section>
    <section id="two">
      <div class="circle">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 100 50"
          class="semicircle"
        >
          <path d="M50 0a50 50 0 0 1 50 50H0A50 50 0 0 1 50 0z" />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="element_wrap">
        <div class="element">
          <img src="./images/main/test_img.png" alt="" />
          <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
          <img src="./images/main/test_img02.png" alt="" />
          <p>2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
          <img src="./images/main/test_img.png" alt="" />
          <p>3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="three">
      <div class="inner_wrap">
        <div class="slide_wrap">
          <div class="slide slide01">
            <div>
              <h4>Ladder Frame Chassis</h4>
              <p>
                Every Jimny owes its off-roading prowess to the Ladder Frame
                structure. Now, it’s your turn to put it to the test. Pick your
                terrain. A thoroughbred off-roader, the torsional rigidity of
                this chassis instils confidence in the driver to master the
                toughest of topographies. While the full-width rigid axles in
                both the front and the rear, keeps you going like a mountain
                goat on the most impassable roads
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide slide02">
            <div>
              <h4>3-link Rigid Axle Suspension With Coil Spring</h4>
              <p>
                The long-stroke 3-link suspension is teamed with full-width
                rigid axles in both the front and rear. This coupled with less
                variation in ground clearance and high tyre grounding force
                enables you to conquer the toughest of terrains. With the rigid
                axle suspension, when an obstacle pushes one wheel up, the axle
                presses the other down, to increase tyre contact in rough road
                conditions.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide slide03">
            <div>
              <h4>Engine Performance</h4>
              <p>
                When you are setting forth into the unknown, the responsive 1.5L
                K15B engine powers you through. Built for off-roading, it
                generates strong torque throughout a wide RPM range for
                unstoppable performance.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="img_wrap"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="four">
      <div class="circle">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 100 50"
          class="semicircle"
        >
          <path d="M50 0a50 50 0 0 1 50 50H0A50 50 0 0 1 50 0z" />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="element_wrap02">
        <div class="element02">
          <img src="./images/main/test_img.png" alt="" />
          <p>1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <!--//container-->
</div>

@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
p {
  color: red;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
section {
  height: 100vh;
}
.circle svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#one .bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518837695005-2083093ee35b")
    no-repeat 50%;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
#two {
  height: auto;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#two .circle {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
#two .element_wrap {
  width: 300%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}
#two .element {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#two .element img {
  width: 300px;
}
#three .inner_wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#three .slide {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#three .slide > div {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 50px;
}
#three .slide h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 125%;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#three .slide p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 125%;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#three .img_wrap {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #6e58c6;
}
#three .slide_wrap {
  width: 50%;
}
#four {
  height: auto;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#four .circle {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
#four .circle img {
  width: 100%;
}
#four .element_wrap02 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}
#four .element02 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

// section #one
let $bg = document.querySelector(".bg");
let $testEffect = gsap
  .timeline({
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: "#one",
      start: "top top",
      end: "+=500",
      pin: true,
      scrub: true,
      pinSpacing: false,
    },
  })
  .to($bg, { scale: 1, duration: 1 })
  .to($, { duration: 1 });

// section #two
let $elements = gsap.utils.toArray(".element");
let $testEffect02 = gsap
  .timeline({
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: ".element_wrap",
      end: () => "+=" + document.querySelector(".element_wrap").offsetWidth,
      pin: true,
      scrub: 1,
    },
  })
  .to($elements, { xPercent: -100 * ($elements.length - 1) });

// section #three
let $slide = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");

let $testEffect03 = gsap
  .timeline({
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: "#three",
      start: "top top",
      end: "+=5000",
      pin: true,
      scrub: true,
      pinSpacing: false,
    },
  })
  .set($slide[0], { opacity: 1 })
  .to($slide[0], { opacity: 0, duration: 0.2 })
  .to($slide[1], { opacity: 1, duration: 0.2 })
  .to($slide[1], { opacity: 0, duration: 0.2 })
  .to($slide[2], { opacity: 1, duration: 0.2 });

//section #four
let $testEffect04 = gsap.timeline({
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".element_wrap02",
    start: "top top",
    pin: true,
    end: "+=1000",
    scrub: true,
  },
});


Try this in section #four  pin: false, scrub: false,
